# How to add filter the post thumbnail before save in database?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have a function in my theme that encode images in base64 and this works perfectly:

```
function image_encoded($img){
    //set the extension of the image
    $filetype=wp_check_filetype($img);
    // Read image path, convert to base64 encoding
    $imageData = base64_encode(wp_remote_fopen($img));
    // Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
    $src = 'data:'.$filetype['ext'].';base64,'.$imageData;
    // return the url of the image encoded in base64
    return $src;
}
```

Now I would like to encode the images before saving them in the database, but this code doesn't work:

```
function save_page_or_post(){
    global $post;
    if(isset($_POST["_thumbnail_id"])) {
        $thumbnail_compressed = image_encoded($_POST["_thumbnail_id"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "_thumbnail_id", $thumbnail_compressed);
    }
}
add_action('save_post','save_page_or_post');
```

Comment: Hi there! So which images? The media files? Or just a post's featured image?

Comment: Hi bro,I like the both images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay - crazy day here...

So I looked at this and tested a few things. I think the sexiest way to do this is to try and return your base64 encoded img src at the... source. (pun not intended)

Have a look at the [image_downsize filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_downsize/) - I believe you can do it in there, either on demand or, if performance becomes an issue, you could then cache your strings in the db. (so first to ask for an image generates the base64 string, and saves it in the db)

My initial tests are conclusive here - this will manage both images added to content through the WYSIWYG editor, and images included by theme functions.

By the way, if you are interested and allow me to re-use your encoding code, I'll gladly make this into an open source plugin...

Oh, and one last comment: you have a small mistake in your base64 string:

```
$src = 'data:'.$filetype['ext'].';base64,'.$imageData;
```

should be

```
$src = 'data:image/'.$filetype['ext'].';base64,'.$imageData;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello bro thanks by your help, sure you can create a plugin , I also can use a filter but I like encoded the url inside the database I am not sure  about how to use image_downsize filter , maybe you can check my [github repository](https://github.com/LeoCR/wp_encode_image) its incomplete for the moment but you can have an idea about what I like to do,so thanks

Comment: Hi! First, thanks for giving me your permission, I really appreciate it. Second, let's discuss approaches and stuff separately, as this is becoming off topic. I tried your website link in your WP exchange profile, but it returns a 404... If you go on my own website (see my profile) you can get my email address. I'd love to keep this discussion going... Thanks!